# How to update persist redux state once after deploy the client side?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I use localStorage as my persist redux state, the code shows below.

```
export const loadState = () => {
  try {
    // localStorage.clear();
    const serializedState = localStorage.getItem("state");
    if (serializedState === null) {
      return undefined;
    }
    return JSON.parse(serializedState);
  } catch (err) {
    return undefined;
  }
};
export const saveState = state => {
  try {
    const serializedState = JSON.stringify(state);
    localStorage.setItem("state", serializedState);
  } catch (err) {
    // Ignore write errors.
  }
};
```

Every time I change my logical reducer, I should run `localStorage.clear();` due to update the localStorage so that the project can run correctly. But it is useless to run the clear method every time, it's better to have a way to control this run once after deploy the project to client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `version` to `localStorage` and compare when to initialize your state from your reducers

before you load your state save the version number

```
// When you update your reducers increase this 
// version to 0.2 => 0.3 => 0.4
// this should run before you call loadState
localStorage.setItem('version', '0.3');

export const loadState = () => {
  try {
    const version = localStorage.getItem('version');
    // When you update your reducers change this comparison
    // to the version number you set in localStorage
    if (version !== '0.1') {
      // Let reducers initial the state if the version is not identical
      return undefined; 
    }
    const serializedState = localStorage.getItem('state');
    if (serializedState === null) {
      return undefined;
    }
    return JSON.parse(serializedState);
  } catch (err) {
    return undefined;
  }
};

export const saveState = (state) => {
  try {
    const serializedState = JSON.stringify(state);
    localStorage.setItem('state', serializedState);
  } catch (err) {
    // Ignore write errors.
  }
};
```

Comment: I know the meaning of this code, very nicely solution for my project, but the logic seems a little bit stranger.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Migrations function of redux-persist. for more detail: https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/blob/master/docs/migrations.md